# how to display total price on magento product page?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I want to display Total price on product page, like this http://www.4imprint.co.uk/tag/61/Ballpens/product/300090/Bic-Protusion-Grip-Pen . any one know how to do it.
should i use $_product->getFinalPrice();

Comment: If you want to display total price same as referenced link, then just JavaScript to calculate the total price base on product price and number of selected product quantity.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you want is `<?php echo $_product->getFinalPrice();?>`

Answer (score 0):

This is even better:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal()); ?>
```